# aws configure not prompting for configuration information

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have a weird situation you might could help me with. I'm on an ec2 instance and I'm running the aws cli to configure s3 sync to a bucket. I'm familiar with the cli and usually when I run `aws configure`, I get the usual prompts for the access keys, but on this machine the only thing that is returned in the cli is `'s3'`. No matter what commands I enter, it only returns 's3'. I've tried deleting the .aws directory (there's only one profile), and nothing...same thing. I've run the list jobs command, and same thing...'s3'.

Is there a command to force the aws cli to reset or something?
thank you for your help!

Comment: Why do you need `configure` if you are on ec2? You can give permission to that `s3` in the ec2 role and do your `sync`.

Comment: Also, try to recreate .aws folder with 755 permissions(`chmod 755`) and create a file called `config` inside with `[default]
region = your region` . Save it and try again.

Comment: Ok I'll give these a try and give an update. Thanks for the tips!